# Concat multiples dataframes within a list

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, concatenation

I have several dataframes in a list, obtained after using `np.array_split` and I want to concat some of then into a single dataframe. In this example, I want to concat 3 dataframes contained in b (all but the 2nd one, which is the element b[1] in the list):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'country':['a','b','c','d'],
  'gdp':[1,2,3,4],
  'iso':['x','y','z','w']})

a = np.array_split(df,4)
i = 1
b = a[:i]+a[i+1:]

desired_final_df = pd.DataFrame({'country':['a','c','d'],
  'gdp':[1,3,4],
  'iso':['x','z','w']})
```

I have tried to create an empty df and then use append through a loop for the elements in b but with no complete success:

```
CV = pd.DataFrame()
CV = [CV.append[(b[i])] for i in b] #try1
CV = [CV.append(b[i]) for i in b] #try2
CV = pd.DataFrame([CV.append[(b[i])] for i in b]) #try3

for i in b:
 CV.append(b) #try4
```

I have reached to a solution which works but it is not efficient:

```
CV = pd.DataFrame()
CV = [CV.append(b) for i in b][0]
```

In this case, I get in CV three times the same dataframe with all the rows and I just get the first of them. However, in my real case, in which I have big datasets, having three times the same would result in much more time of computation.

How could I do that without repeating operations?

Comment: Please, provide an example of the result you want to get.

Comment: @sentence donee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To cancatenate multiple DFs, resetting index, use [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
pd.concat(b, ignore_index=True)
```

**output**

```
    country gdp iso
0   a   1   x
1   c   3   z
2   d   4   w
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html), `DataFrame.append` does not work in-place, like lists. The resulting DataFrame object is returned instead. Catching that object should be enough for what you need:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
for next_df in list_of_dfs:
    df = df.append(next_df)
```

You may want to use the keyword argument `ignore_index=True` in the `append` call so that the indices become continuous, instead of starting from 0 for each appended DataFrame (assuming that the index of the DataFrames in the list all start from 0).